# Navigation written inside header tag but shown below the header

Tags: html, css

So I had some problems making a responsive navigation bar with Gatsby. After 2 weeks, I've finally managed to make it work but there is one last problem.

I've put my navigation inside my header for logic reasons. Normally the navbar is hidden but when you touch or click the hamburger menu, the navigation is visible but the point is:

My header is a P tag together with the Icon div. When toggled, the navigation is forced inside the header but I want to make my navigation appear BELOW the header.

Any ways to do this?
This is my code for the header

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Navbar from '../navbar/navbar'


const Header = () => {
const [toggleNav, setToggleNav]=useState(false);

const showNav = () => setToggleNav(!toggleNav);


    return(
       <header>
         <div className="topbar ">         
            <p>STIJN REYGAERTS</p>
                  <div className='Icon' onClick={showNav}>
                     <div></div>
                     <div></div>
                     <div></div>          
                   </div>
               </div>    
            <div className={`${toggleNav ? 'NavigationVisible': 'Navigation' }`}><Navbar /></div>       
       </header>    
    )
}

export default Header
```

Comment: provide the code if you want answer

Comment: I've edited. Can you take a look at it please!